# How to access different components using props

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I'm trying to access state from my Login.jsx component but I'm currently working in the UI.jsx component that is displayed once you are logged in.

My logout button in my Login component should be rendered when your state is set to logged in, but I don't want to render it from Login.jsx. I want to render it from UI.jsx.

The button is displayed once I'm not mounting any components but UI takes over as soon as I load it and it won't show up. All my states are in Login but there should be a way to access it from UI, right?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your situation, but you can access to component methods via ref. For example, if your UI component declares its Login as follows:

```
<Login/>
```

you could do this:

```
<Login ref={(r)=>this.login=r}/>
```

Then you have access from UI's methods to Login's methods using this.login.method().

By the way, wouldn't it be better to store login state in UI component, and update it using a handler?

```
<Login handler={(ok)=>this.setState({loggedIn: ok})} />
```

and then inside Login component method that checks login:

```
doLogin () {
  const ok = //check login
  this.props.handler(ok);
}
```